# How to install VSTO outlook addin for all users in machine using WIX Toolset?

Tags: outlook, wix, windows-installer, vsto, outlook-addin

I have created outlook addin. I haave created installer using WIX toolset to install addin on client machine. I have registered VSTO file in **HKCU** hive at path **Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\AddIns**

Current code for registering component is as below

```
<Component Id="Registry_Manifest">
          <RegistryValue Id="RegKey_Manifest" Root="HKCU"
                         Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\AddIns\xyz"
                         Name="Manifest" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]xyz.vsto|vstolocal"
                         Type="string" KeyPath="yes" />
        </Component>
```

Current code is working fine but registering addin for only current user. It is not viewed by another users on same machine.

I have to know How to enable addin for all users on system.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just replaced HKCU hive by HKLM hive. It will create new path in HKLM hive for manifest file and applied to all users also.

Comment: Why did you write your own answer when someone else provided it to you?

Answer (score 8):

By definition, HKCU is for the current installing user. That means that the more obvious solution would to create those entries in HKLM, assuming that per-machine is supported (sometimes Office products appear to be designed for per-user use, not per-machine).